# Xamarin Forms Automatic Image SlideShow/Carousel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm completely new to Xamarin Forms but I've managed to create a simple app that has multiple pages and I am able to navigate between pages.

I've added images, buttons and other basic controls successfully and it looks pretty good.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to create an automatic carousel of multiple images on a page. Any google searches return the CarouselPage which enables a user to swipe the screen to change pages.

I'm considering a horizontal scroller with the 3 images but it doesn't really have the same effect - the user will have to move themselves through the images!

Has anyone found a way of doing this? Any hints or tips would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code a combination of a c# timer, a carrousel page, and contentPage's with images on the background I have done something similar but using buttons to navigate the carrousel page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SEEForgeX.Views
{
class CarouselView : CarouselPage
{
    ContentPage image1,image2,image3,image4;
    public CarouselView()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        string btnPrevTitle = "< Prev";
        string btnNextTitle = "Next >";
        Color btnColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        Color btnTextColor = Color.White;
        LayoutOptions btnPosY = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
        LayoutOptions btnPrevPosX = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
        LayoutOptions btnNextPosX = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
        Font buttonFont = Font.SystemFontOfSize(16, FontAttributes.Bold);
        int btnWidth = 100;
        string exitBtnImg = "close.png";

        Button nextBtn1 = new Button
        {
            Text = btnNextTitle,
            BackgroundColor = btnColor,
            TextColor = btnTextColor,
            VerticalOptions = btnPosY,
            HorizontalOptions = btnNextPosX,
            Font = buttonFont,
            WidthRequest = btnWidth
        };

         Button prevBtn2 = new Button
            {
                Text = btnPrevTitle,
                BackgroundColor = btnColor,
                TextColor = btnTextColor,
                VerticalOptions = btnPosY,
                HorizontalOptions = btnPrevPosX,
                Font = buttonFont,
                WidthRequest = btnWidth
            };

        image1 = new ContentPage 
        {
            BackgroundImage = "slide_01.jpg",
            Content = new StackLayout 
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Padding = 0,

                Children = { 
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                        Padding = new Thickness(0,10,10,0),
                        Children = { exitBtn1 }
                    },
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                        Padding = 20,
                        Children = { nextBtn1 }
                    }
                }
            },
        };

        image2 = new ContentPage
        {
            BackgroundImage = "slide_02.jpg",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Padding = 0,
                Children = { 
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                        Padding = new Thickness(0,10,10,0),
                        Children = { exitBtn2 }
                    },
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                        Padding = 20,
                        Children = {prevBtn2, nextBtn2}
                    }
                }
            },

        };
//This is the children of the parent view is like adding stacklayout.children.add(foo) but since              my parent class is a CarouselPage I can access Children its children
            Children.Add(image1);
            Children.Add(image2);

    void prevBtn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentPage = image1;
    }

    void nextBtn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentPage = image2;
    }

    private async void exitBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

I am not implementing the timer but it should not be difficult, maybe you can even use a loop.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your reply. Looks like this is the route I will take. I was thinking a long the same lines but I was hoping for some kind of built in carousel control...Thanks.

Comment: @Rick : Hi Rick, Do you found a solution for automatic slideshow? I want an automatic slideshow that run in bg of my login page. I can not use c# timer in Xamarin.Form Portable :(

Comment: @minamorsali Maybe you can use Device.StartTimer?
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/p/System.TimeSpan/System.Func%7BSystem.Boolean%7D/

Comment: @MarioGalván sorry no, we abandoned Xamarin as it didn't seem to fulfil our requirements at the time. I think it is a lot better now though, especially as Microsoft have bought it. Though I still think there's a lot of custom coding for UI features in forms,